# How to calculate specific heat capacity of an alloy

Tags: heat

I have done an experiment in which I measured the specific heat capacity of a coin. I would like to compare the results to the actual value. I have found out that the coin is made of Cupronickel alloy (for simplicity let's assume it's just 75% copper and 25% nickel).

Knowing the SHC values of the two elements (copper and nickel) how would I go about calculating the theoretical value of the SHC of the Cupronickel alloy, so that I can compare it to my experiment's results?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think there is a reliable way of calculating the specific heat of a metal alloy as it depends on the details of the interactions between the metals. A quick Google finds a value for the specific heat of CuNi25 of 390J/(kgK).

Comment: Could you provide link to the source, please? Thanks.

Comment: http://www.copper.org/applications/cuni/txt_dki.html, http://www.cuivre.org/contenu/docs/doc/pdf/CuNi/CuNi25.pdf